# Excel VBA Workbooks.open with optional parameters

Tags: vba, excel

I'm sure this is a very basic question that has a very basic answer but so far I can't make my Excel macro work.

I am trying to open an Excel workbook and input the optional *password* parameter. However, whenever I do this, I get the error *Compile error expected: Named Parameter*.

This is my current code

```
Sub password_opening_test()
Workbooks.Open Filename:="E:\password protecting macrotest.xlsx",,,,Password:="test"
Range("G7").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "hello"
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

I've also tried it by adding square brakets in between the commas but I still recieve the error (which is highlighted by the first comma).

Thanks very much for reading

Comment: try without the extras commas `Workbooks.Open Filename:="E:\password protecting macrotest.xlsx", Password:="test"` As long as you specify which argument you are passing (i.e. - `Password:=`) the extra commas for the other arguments are not necessary.

Comment: Great, thanks Scott, this worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two options available:

1. As Scott details in his comment - get rid of your commas

2.
Just use the arguments in their correct positions

```
Sub password_opening_test()
  Workbooks.Open "E:\password protecting macrotest.xlsx",,,,"test"
  Range("G7").Select
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "hello"
  ActiveWorkbook.Save
  ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

For the record I prefer Scott's approach as it is much more readable in future re-visits to the code. I like to use line seperators so it looks like this:

```
Sub password_opening_test()
  Workbooks.Open _
      Filename:="E:\password protecting macrotest.xlsx", _  
      Password:="test"
  Range("G7").Select
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "hello"
  ActiveWorkbook.Save
  ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: So I have to ask. If both are options that work, which one is the better practice: 1) `Workbooks.Open "E:\password protecting macrotest.xlsx", Password:="test"` or 2) `Workbooks.Open "E:\password protecting macrotest.xlsx",,,,"test"`? Option 1 seems to be the better practice.

Comment: @IronMan upto you - I prefer spelling out arguments in a particular layout - I'll add to answer.

Comment: your response is dead on. I guess it would be up to the individual coder.

Comment: Thanks Whytheq, both options worked!

And as you say I agree i prefer the second option, definitely improves the readability of the code